# Using require.js with jasmine to load scripts returning 404

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine

I'm using Backbonejs and am using require.js to load each dependent backbone widget before firing up my app and putting everything in a custom namespace, in this case "Foo". I'd like to have Jasmine load up this loader file and pick up all the dependent javascripts (located in /public/js of my main app), however, I'm getting all 404's as Jasmine doesn't know about the /public/js directory on port 8888. How can I get jasmine to load these javascripts?

```
  Foo = {}; 
  jQuery(function(){
    var include = ['/js/widget.js','/js/delta_widget.js','/js/inbox.js','/js/time_widget.js','/js/high_stock_widget.js','/js/daily_summary_widget.js'];
    require(include,function(){
      $.getScript('/js/app.js');
    }); 
  });
```

For each of the javascripts, I'm getting:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://0.0.0.0:8888/js/widget.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that your Jasmine loader file / SpecRunner is in a different directory than your require.js loader (main.js by default). You will have to configure require.js to use a different base path by doing the following:

```
jQuery(function(){
require.config(
{
  baseUrl: '/public'
});

var include = ['js/widget.js',
               'js/delta_widget.js',
               'js/inbox.js',
               'js/time_widget.js',
               'js/high_stock_widget.js',
               'js/daily_summary_widget.js'];

require(include,function()
{
  $.getScript('/js/app.js');
});
```

You have to configure the above "baseUrl" property to point to the proper URL/Path.
For example, if your Jasmine SpecRunner is located in:

base
- main.js
- js
-- widget.js
-- app.js
- Libs
-- Jasmine
--- SpecRunner.html

then you need to configure

```
baseUrl: "../../"
```

Hope this helps.